# Проблема с чекбоксами

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

При отметке чекбоксов все работает правильно, но когда отмечены оба чекбокса - после снятия отметки с одного из них, исчезают все надписи

```
<html>
<head>
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript" SRC="jquery-1.3.2.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
//A1        
    $("#A1").css("display","none");
    $("#maincb1").click(function(){
    if ($("#maincb1").is(":checked")){$("#A1").show("fast");}else{$("#A1").hide("fast");}});
//B2        
    $("#B2").css("display","none");
    $("#maincb2").click(function(){
    if ($("#maincb2").is(":checked")){$("#B2").show("fast");}else{$("#B2").hide("fast");}});
//A1B2      
    $("#A1B2").css("display","none");
    $("#maincb1, #maincb2").click(function(){
    if ($("#maincb1").is(":checked") && $("#maincb2").is(":checked")){
                $("#A1B2").show("fast") && $("#A1").hide("fast") && $("#B2").hide("fast");
        }
        else{   $("#A1B2").hide("fast");

        }});
});

</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<body>
    <FORM ACTION="" METHOD="post">
        <!-- A1 -->                 
            <div>
                <INPUT TYPE="checkbox" id="maincb1"> A1
            </div>
        <!-- B2 -->                 
            <div>
                <INPUT TYPE="checkbox" id="maincb2"> B2
            </div>

        <!-- HIDDEN --> 
            <DIV ID="A1" STYLE="display:none;">
                <P class="tour">A1</P>
            </div>
            <DIV ID="B2" STYLE="display:none;">
                <P class="tour">B2</P>
            </div>
            <DIV ID="A1B2" STYLE="display:none;">
                <P class="tour">A1 and B2</P>
            </div>
    </FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавить еще условие внутрь `$("#maincb1, #maincb2").click` в блок, если оба не выбраны с проверкой на то, кто останется:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //A1        
  $("#A1").css("display", "none");
  $("#maincb1").click(function() {
    if ($("#maincb1").is(":checked")) {
      $("#A1").show("fast");
    } else {
      $("#A1").hide("fast");
    }
  });
  //B2        
  $("#B2").css("display", "none");
  $("#maincb2").click(function() {
    if ($("#maincb2").is(":checked")) {
      $("#B2").show("fast");
    } else {
      $("#B2").hide("fast");
    }
  });
  //A1B2      
  $("#A1B2").css("display", "none");
  $("#maincb1, #maincb2").click(function() {
    if ($("#maincb1").is(":checked") && $("#maincb2").is(":checked")) {
      $("#A1B2").show("fast") && $("#A1").hide("fast") && $("#B2").hide("fast");
    } else {
      $("#A1B2").hide("fast"); 
      if ($("#maincb2").is(":checked")) { // если остался B2
        $("#B2").show("fast"); // покажем B2
      } else if ($("#maincb1").is(":checked")) { // если остался A1
        $("#A1").show("low"); // покажем A1
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<FORM ACTION="" METHOD="post">
  <div>
    <INPUT TYPE="checkbox" id="maincb1"> A1
  </div>
  <div>
    <INPUT TYPE="checkbox" id="maincb2"> B2
  </div>
  <DIV ID="A1" STYLE="display:none;">
    <P class="tour">A1</P>
  </div>
  <DIV ID="B2" STYLE="display:none;">
    <P class="tour">B2</P>
  </div>
  <DIV ID="A1B2" STYLE="display:none;">
    <P class="tour">A1 and B2</P>
  </div>
</FORM>
```